# Auto Layout - Make UITextView, not UIImageView, stretch the container view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have 3 views:

- a `UIImageView` (blank, no image set)
- a `UITextView` with `isScrollEnabled` set to false
- a `UIView` container (gray background) that contains the `UIImageView` and `UITextView`

I'm trying to get the container to resize based on the `UITextView`'s contents. It works well — but as soon as I set an image, the container seems to resize based on the `UIImageView`.

| Shorter text | Longer text | After setting image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Image on left of text, gray background hugs the text] | [image: Image on left of text, gray background hugs the text which is taller] | [image: Image on left of text, gray background hugs the image instead] |

I do want the `UIImageView` to grow and *fill* the container view's height, though. I just don't want it to *stretch* the container view. That's the `UITextView`'s job. Here's what my constraints look like:

[image: Storyboard constraints]

And the storyboard code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="18122" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="18093"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="AutoLayoutImage" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6rW-8U-sdf" userLabel="Container View">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="197.5" width="414" height="501"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="a4K-HY-RKq">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="150" height="501"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="150" id="Pim-0S-hxs"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </imageView>
                                    <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" scrollEnabled="NO" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9HO-GD-av1">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="150" y="0.0" width="264" height="501"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <mutableString key="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.</mutableString>
                                        <color key="textColor" systemColor="labelColor"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                        <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                    </textView>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemGrayColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="a4K-HY-RKq" secondAttribute="bottom" id="1sx-AM-Fqw"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="9HO-GD-av1" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="a4K-HY-RKq" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Jyx-tB-n4x"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="9HO-GD-av1" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6rW-8U-sdf" secondAttribute="top" id="QxL-cJ-Jed"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="9HO-GD-av1" secondAttribute="trailing" id="UGU-yx-lKn"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="a4K-HY-RKq" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6rW-8U-sdf" secondAttribute="top" id="WWU-dr-LHm"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="9HO-GD-av1" secondAttribute="bottom" id="fuH-5Z-rGP"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="a4K-HY-RKq" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6rW-8U-sdf" secondAttribute="leading" id="wdj-Os-8pf"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="6rW-8U-sdf" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Veu-vt-Hmb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6rW-8U-sdf" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="hXI-pR-7IQ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6rW-8U-sdf" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="trailing" id="zQE-bH-DL3"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="131.8840579710145" y="114.50892857142857"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="labelColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemGrayColor">
            <color red="0.55686274509803924" green="0.55686274509803924" blue="0.57647058823529407" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

[And here's the image that I used](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/ImageSmall.jpg). How do I make the container resize based on the `UITextView` and not the `UIImageView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the vertical content compression resistance priority of the image view to be lower than the vertical content hugging priority of the text view. For example, I've set the former to "low" and the latter to "high", and it works.

Image view:

[image]

Text View:

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks! I did play around with "Content Compression Resistance Priority," but evidently not enough. Setting the `UIImageView`'s to `749` didn't work, but `250` did, as shown in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use constraints to resolve your problem!
set text view constraint height equal view (or set equal top and bottom) height constraint and set static image view constraint height (ex: imageView height constraints = 250)